# xuggler convertingh mp4 to avi

Tags: java

Im using xuggler to convert mp4 file to avi file.the conversion is going on well but my program is not coming out of while loop please anybody help me 
this is my code

```
IMediaReader mediaReader = ToolFactory.makeReader(inputFilename);
IMediaWriter mediaWriter = ToolFactory.makeWriter(outputFilename, mediaReader);
mediaReader.addListener(mediaWriter);
IMediaViewer mediaViewer = ToolFactory.makeViewer(true);
mediaReader.addListener(mediaViewer);
while (mediaReader.readPacket() == null);
```

thanks in advace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding a Debug Listener to find out what's wrong?

```
 // add a debug listener to the writer to see media writer events
 writer.addListener(ToolFactory.makeDebugListener());
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, [here](http://build.xuggle.com/view/Stable/job/xuggler_jdk5_stable/javadoc/java/api/com/xuggle/mediatool/IMediaReader.html#readPacket%28%29) , the method that is called as the `while` condition returns:

> null if there are more packets to read, otherwise return an IError instance.

maybe you are not waiting enough for the app to come out of the `while`?

Comment: @bluefoot thanks for your reply no i have run the application which will conver 757 kb file and i went out and came back after 10 mins still the application didnt come out of the loop what should i do now

Comment: you don't return. the method returns if there's nothing more to read. You can get the `IError` returned if you do :
    `IError err = null;
    while(err ==null) {
        err = mediaReader.readPacket()
    }`
 I suggest you debug the code to see the problem. Is your memory use increasing while the app is in the loop?

Comment: @thank you all for ur replies i have got it thanks once again

Comment: well, if you solve it, please tell us how. and accept an answer :)

Comment: @bluefoot i have used debuglistener which was stated by thomas

Comment: and what was the actual problem?